# How to configure query for document library search box

Tags: sharepoint-online

Background : In SP2013 Online , for every document library we have a search box to search within the document library. The query returns results based on document metadata + match within the document.
Requirement : Search result should match only from Document title and NOT within the document content. 
For e.g. : For the below mentioned documents, if the search is keyed for word  “test” : 2 results are found.
1<sup>st</sup> with document title matching the query i.e. ‘Test.docx’ - REQUIRED
2<sup>nd</sup> – Document containing the query text – NOT REQUIRED

Answer (score 0):

Good day...

A quick note. You mention document title. When you say document title do you mean the Title column when a document is uploaded, or do you mean the document name.

If you mean the title column, than use this search query.

**Title:[Query]**

If you mean the file name, than use this query.

**Filename:[Query]**

Let's assume its the file name. If you want to find a filename that matches and entry, and than also contains content, you can use some operators to help with that. Here is an example query.

**Filename:MarchResults AND "End of quarter"**

This will find all filenames that contain the word MarchResults in the file name only AND also have anywhere in the metadata "End of quarter". Both must be true to return. Using an OR instead of an AND will allow results to be returned if either or true. Let me know if that helps.